# Debug logging in Thunderbird's userChrome.js

Tags: debugging, thunderbird

I'm trying to debug a custom javascript for Thunderbird that is defined in userChrome.js. Unfortunately I did not find a decent way to log to the javascript console. Is there an easy way to dump some information to an easily accessible console/logfile so that I can debug my script? I have console² installed and tried calling

```
throw Error("foobar");
```

already, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does Application.console.log("message") work?

Comment: Yes, it did, thanks. For some reason, the userChrome.js has not been loaded at all. After installing the userChromeJS add-on it worked.

Answer (score -1):

1. Write `console.log("hello");` in your `*.uc.js` file.
2. Open browser console(ctrl + shift + j).

Now, you can see message from file `*.uc.js`.